# Register an account using Devise from a mobile app using a json post

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, api, devise

I'm new to rails and I'm hoping to get help with registering an account on my rails app from an android device.
Currently I'm using the Devise gem for my user registrations. I was able to get user authentications working, using devise's tokens, but I'm stuck on how to register for an account from my mobile phone.

I'm looking at two approaches so far. My first attempt was to create a new controller called MobileRegistrationsController and having a create method like so:

```
class Api::V1::MobileRegistrationsController  < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    @user = User.create!(params[user])
    @user.ensure_authentication_token!

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end
end
```

Here's my routes folder. I followed the railscast tutorial for this:

```
namespace :api do

  namespace :v1  do
    resources :tokens,:only => [:create, :destroy], :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
    match 'register' => 'mobile_registrations#create', :via => "post", :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
  end
end
```

From here, when I use my REST client to try to send a post request to

```
localhost:3000/api/v1/register
```

I get the error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant    Api::V1::MobileRegistrationsController):
```

So I'm guessing I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.
I've googled around, and perhaps overriding the Devise sessions controller is a better way to go?
Does anyone have experience with this, that could help?

Thanks!

UPDATE: So I'm trying a new route. By adding this to my routes folder

```
devise_scope :user do
   match "api/v1/register" => "devise/registrations#create"
end
```

When I try sending a post request to this. I'm getting another error:

```
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

Which I guess is better than what I had before. So now I just need to figure out how to get my rails authenticity token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright. So I was able to figure it out. In case someone stumbles upon this and has the same issue. It looks like it was a combination of a few bugs in my code.

I renamed my controller, since I believe the "uninitialized constant" error was a result of poorly naming my controller. I just renamed my controller to RegistersController for simplicities sake. So that fixed my Routing error.

This lead me to a new bug which was the CSRF token.
I added the line:

> skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create

Which skipped the verify method. This is a big nebulous for me, since I'm thinking that would add vulnerabilities to my app, so if someone has a better solution for this, let me know.

So after that, I was left with a new bug in my create method, which was:

> Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank

To fix this, I changed my create method to:

> @user = User.create!(:email => params[:email], :password => params[:password], :password_confirmation => params[:password_confirmation])

I also changed my json response to include my authenticity token, which I store as a sharedpreference in my android app.

> format.json { render :status=>200, :json=>{:token=>@user.authentication_token, :user => @user} }